# Возможно ли использовать два различных варианта функции в зависимости от ее аргументов?

Tags: python, функции, function-overloading

У меня есть две функции :

```
def remote_command(data, cmd, wait_for_output) -> dict:
...
```

и

```
def remote_command(client, cmd, wait_for_output) -> dict:
...
```

Они обе выполняют действие разным способом и требуют разных аргументов. Первую я импортировал в файл, а вторую создал в нем. Мне в моем файле нужны обе функции, но сейчас они переопределяют друг друга. Можно ли как-то указывать какую функцию я хочу использовать в данный момент в зависимости от аргументов?

Comment: Нельзя. Если разные аргументы, то создайте две функции. Вам же известно какие аргументы в каком месте программы. Ну или проверяйте в самой функции, что там пришло, и выполняйте соответствующие действия.

Comment: Раз одна из функций импортируемая вы можете импортировать ее с другим именем чрез `from <file> import remote_command as remote_command_ext`

Comment: Есть еще и декораторы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно сделать используя, например, именованные аргументы:

```
def remote_command(cmd, wait_for_output, data=None, client=None) -> dict:
    if data:
        return 'Command with data'
    elif client:
        return 'Command with client'

data = 'data'
client = 'client'
print(remote_command('cmd', 'wait_for_output', data=data))
print(remote_command('cmd', 'wait_for_output', client=client))
```

Но с точки зрения архитектуры лучше сделать декомпозицию на две функции, назвав их по-разному, раз они действительно выполняют действие **разными** способами:

```
def remote_data_command(cmd, wait_for_output, data) -> dict
def remote_client_command(cmd, wait_for_output, client) -> dict
```